# CrystalReportViewer acting very slow on loading large number of pages

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer, large-data

I'm loading a large number of data into CrystalReportViewer (About 100 pages), In CrystalRepor XI application it loades pages very fast, but in My VB WinForm application (with a CrystalReportViewer) it loads data very slow. What's the problem? Please Help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do any profiling or at least step through your code in debugger?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that in other thread but the problem exists yet, I tried to get last page index, I tried to use COM version of crystal report viewer, I tried to change data source type (DataTable, DataReader, Stored Procedure, Command, ...) but nothing works for me, It seems the crystal report viewer component is not working async!

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to load your crystalreportviewer before you fill it and make it invisible? Then, when you need to show the data, you can make it visible.